# PDE- Wave equation on semi-infinite string

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am becoming frustrated in trying to understand the wave equation in the semiinfinte case:
$ u_{tt} -c^2 u_{xx} =0 $  when $ x\geq 0 $

$u(x,0)=f(x) $

$ u_t(x,0)= g(x) $

and

$ u(0,t)=0 $ or $ u_x (0,t)=0$ . I know that in the first case we can expand $f,g$ as odd functions to $ (-\infty, \infty) $ and in the second case, we can expand $f,g$ as even functions.

The problem is that I can't understand why in the first case we need them to be odd but in the second case we need them to be even.... Can someone help me figure this out?

I couldn't find any good explanation online...

Thanks !

Comment: Latex hint:  to get $u_{xx}$, use braces around the subscripts; thus, to get $u_{xx}$, type u_{xx}, not u_xx.  In these examples I obviously omitted the dollar signs.

Comment: I think the reason is as simple as observing that odd functions are zero at $x=0$ and even functions have zero slope at $x=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we have the wave equation in the semi plane:

$$
u_{tt}- c^2 u_{xx}=0  \\
u(x,0)=f(x) \\
u_t(x,0)=g(x)
$$

The solution is $$u(x,t)=\frac{f(x+ct)+f(x-ct)}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\int_{x-ct}^{x+ct}g(\tau)d\tau$$.

In particular 
$$u(0,t)=\frac{f(ct)+f(-ct)}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\int_{-ct}^{ct}g(\tau)d\tau = F(t) + G(t),$$

where (can be verified easily)
$F:=\frac{f(ct)+f(-ct)}{2}$ is an even function and $G= \frac{1}{2}\int_{-ct}^{ct}g(\tau)d\tau$ is and odd function.

Note that if we have the aditional condition $u(0,t)=0$, then F and G must(should?) be zero. Then f and g must be odd functions. That is the reason why we should make an odd extension.

The case $u_x(0,t)=0$ is similar.